Trouble-shooting SmartyException: "Unable to load template ... in 'file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl'"
I'm trying to learn how to add my first page to my CiviCRM extension. All it want is for civicrm/dev to display "Hello World."
I think I have Page/Dev.tpl in the correct location, but civicrm/dev errors:
SmartyException: "Unable to load template ... in 'file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl'"
Based on the traceback, I think I'm using smarty4.
I want to learn, but I'm stuck for trouble-shooting ideas?
